# Dynamically Change image when navigating to different routes

Tags: vue.js

I have a Banner component. I want to change the image in there when i am navigating to different routes. Its like using different banner images for separate inner pages. I want to use that banner component as a nested component in other components.

```html
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
     <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto custom-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
       <router-link to="/">home</router-link>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
       <router-link to="/about-Us">about us</router-link>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
       <router-link to="/characters">characters</router-link>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
       <router-link to="/our-comics">comics</router-link>
      </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Banner component

```html
    <template>
      <section class="banner-outer">
        <img src="../assets/banner.jpg" alt class="img-fluid" />
        <div class="banner-content-outer">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="banner-content-inner">
              <h1>EXPLORE THE UNIVERSE</h1>
              <h5>Dive into the dazzling domain of all the classic characters you love ...</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </template>
```

About Us Component, Contact us Component

```html
    <template>
      <banner />
    </template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each page component, pass the image in as a **`prop`** to the banner component...

```
<template>
        <banner which-banner="//path/to/img.png"></banner>
        <div>component page content...</div>
</template>
```

In the banner Component...

```
<script>
...
  {
      props: ['whichBanner']
  }
..
</script>
<template>
  <section class="banner-outer">
    <img :src="whichBanner" alt class="img-fluid" />
    <div class="banner-content-outer">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="banner-content-inner">
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
```

[Vue Codeply](https://codeply.com/p/H4SLqUBGtR)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`beforeEach`](https://router.vuejs.org/fr/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#interception-globale) :

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    // check current route to set the valid image 
    // in vuex or localstorage or even a global window variable 

    if(to === 'about-us') {
      // using global variable
      window.bannerImagePath = 'path/to/about-us/banner.png';
      // localstorage
      localStorage.setItem('bannerImagePath', 'path/to/about-us/banner.png');
    } else if( ... ) { ... }


    return next();
});
```

Then you can get it in `BannerComponent` inside `mounted()` or set a `method` for that

Example :

```html
<img :src="getCurrentBannerImage()" alt class="img-fluid" />
```

```js
methods: {
  getCurrentBannerImage() {
    // global variable example
    return require(window.bannerImagePath) // or any storage you choose
    // localStorage
    let _item = localStorage.getItem('bannerImagePath');
    return require(_item) // or any storage you choose
  }
},
```

Comment: As i am new to Vue Can you please how can i set the image from assets/images in router.beforeEach function

Comment: @RAHULKUNDU i've just updated my answer for both examples global and localStorage, for vuex you can use it later :)